# django bytesIO to base64 String & return as JSON

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using python 3 & I have this code, trying to get base64 out of stream and returnn as json  - but not working.

```
       stream = BytesIO()
       img.save(stream,format='png')
       return base64.b64encode(stream.getvalue())
```

in my view, I have:

```
hm =mymap()
    strHM = hm.generate(data)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"img": strHM}),content_type="application/json"  )
```

getting error  is not JSON serializable.  base64.b64encode(stream.getvalue()) seems giving bytes

Comment: strHM is base64.b64encode(stream.getvalue())

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Python 3.x, [`base64.b64encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) accepts a `bytes` object and returns a `bytes` object.

```
>>> base64.b64encode(b'a')
b'YQ=='
>>> base64.b64encode(b'a').decode()
'YQ=='
```

You need to convert it to `str` object, using [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode):

```
return base64.b64encode(stream.getvalue()).decode()
```

Comment: Any drawbacks to leaving the default argument of [`encoding="utf-8"`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode), considering UTF-8 isn't being used here?

Comment: @esmail, utf-8 is default in Python 3.x, so I think there's no drawback. If you're not sure, you can specify `ascii` explicitly.

Comment: There has to be a better way, you're encoding and then decoding again

Comment: @Mojimi, encoding (base64!): bytes -> bytes, decoding: bytes -> str. If you're using python 2.7, you may not need decode if you just want str (byte-string in python 2.x).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a simpler solution.

Simply get the bytes from the stream and pass them to b64encode.

```
b64encode(f.getvalue())
```

Output (also bytes)

```
b'c2VwYWwgbGVuZ3RoIChjbSksc2V...'
```