# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to bytes.__format__

Tags: python, sqlite

Hi I'm trying to print an sqlite file to a readable format. I'm using dionea honeynet's python script. I encounter this error every time I run the script:

```
File "./readlogsqltree.py", line 268, in print_logins
    login['login_password']))

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to bytes.__format__
```

The login['login_password'] is a variable taken from a select statement. Here is the function that is being called:

```
def print_logins(cursor, connection, indent):
    r = cursor.execute("""
        SELECT 
            login_username,
            login_password
        FROM 
            logins
        WHERE connection = ?""", (connection, ))
    logins = resolve_result(r)
    for login in logins:
        print("{:s} login - user:'{:s}' password:'{:s}'".format(
            ' ' * indent,
            login['login_username'],
            login['login_password']))
```

Resolve result function:

```
def resolve_result(resultcursor):
    names = [resultcursor.description[x][0] for x in range(len(resultcursor.description))]
    resolvedresult = [ dict(zip(names, i)) for i in resultcursor]
    return resolvedresult
```

Cursor:

```
def print_db(opts, args):
    dbpath = 'logsql.sqlite'
    if len(args) >= 1:
        dbpath = args[0]
    print("using database located at {0}".format(dbpath))
    dbh = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
    cursor = dbh.cursor()
```

Comment: Why are you using `{:s}`? Change that to `{}` and it should print out.

Comment: It was part of the code

Comment: OK, can you verify that the `login_password` column is not of `bytes` type in your database?

Comment: password is `text` type. The thing is some of the entries are empty.

Comment: That may be the problem. The reason for the exception you're getting is because you're trying to format a byte as a string, which you can't do like that. If you don't want to replace the `{:s}` in the string, then try adding a cast of the password to a string. So the very last line of your code will look like this: `str(login['login_password'])))`. It really shouldn't matter. The code is just printing here. It's not going to impact the rest of the program.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering this error when converting some python2 script to python3:

```sh
  File "/home/user/Documents/projects/tf-booking/tensorflow-object-detection-example/object_detection_app/app.py", line 152, in encode_image
    base64.b64encode(image_buffer.getvalue()))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to bytes.__format__
```

Solution was to use `base64.b64encode(image_buffer.getvalue()).decode()` instead of `base64.b64encode(image_buffer.getvalue())` as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241996/django-bytesio-to-base64-string-return-as-json).

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3, decode the string using [`decode('utf-8')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode) before calling [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format)